# Firebase library order

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am making a webpage with a Firebase database.

I am new, I want to know if the order of the libraries do matter.

My libraries look like this:

```
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
     <<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
     <script src="uploadr.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <title>Uploader</title>   
</head>
```

and I keep getting tons of errors [image]

If I delete the second half and leave it like this, I don't have any errors. But I really need the auth library.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a version mismatch between the individual product libraries that you're including.  You have a mix of 6.2.4 and 7.6.1. All of the libraries provided by Firebase should have the same version, otherwise they might not work with each other. The latest version as of today is 7.6.2.

The order does matter somewhat.  As you can see in the error message, firebase-app.js should appear first, and everything else should follow in whatever order you want.